# Question about bounds on $g(x) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac1{x+y} f(y)\,dy$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $$g(x) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac1{x+y} f(y)\,dy$$ where $x$ is (strictly) between $0$ and $\infty$. Prove that if $f$ is in $L_1(0, \infty$) then $g$ is not, and in general, if $f$ is in $L_\infty$, then $g$ is unbounded.

I noticed that

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac1{x+y} \,dy \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(*)$$

diverges, and that in the case of $L_1$, we could show that $$||g||_1 = \int_0^{\infty} \Big| \int_0^{\infty}\frac1{x+y} f(y)dy\Big|\ dx \leq \int_0^{\infty}  \int_0^{\infty}\frac1{x+y} |f(y)|dydx $$ and show that this upper bound diverges due to (*). However, I'm not sure what this means for $||g||_1$ itself, and I don't know where to begin with the $L_\infty$ case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannaot say that if $f$ is in $L^{1}$ then $g$ is not in $L^{1}$. For example, if $f=0$ then $g$ is in $L^{1}$. But if $f$ is also non-negative $g$ is not in $L^{1}$ unless $f=0$ almost everywhere.  By Fubini/Tonelli Theorem $\int g(x)dx=\int \int \frac 1 {x+y} f(y) dxdy =\infty$ since $\int \frac 1 {x+y}dx=\infty$ for each $y$.

For the $L^{\infty}$ case take $f=1$